# osclass 404 error on adlisting view when transferred to other doamin

Tags: osclass

When I transfer OS class from one domain to other, only homepage show. On ad click showing 404 error. In config file I have changed old details to new. Please provide guidance. What changes are required to transfer it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Answer (score 0):

- You should check your OsClass `config.php` file first. Check your new domain configuration is correct or not.
- Check `.htaccess` file from your OsClass project root directory. If there is some configurations, Then change it to default.
- Check the permalink settings from your `'oc-admin` dashboard. Also check the apache `rewrite` module is enabled.

You can see details from [Tutorial: How to transfer to another domain osclass](http://forums.osclass.org/general-help/tutorial-how-to-transfer-to-another-domain-osclass/)